# SQL join two tables with SUM based on two conditions (columns)

Tags: mysql, join, sum

the base table is **TABLE_1**.

I want to "join SUM values" from TABLE_2 to TABLE_1 based on columns **NUMBER** and **TOOL**  like IMAGE below.

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6fKz.png)

I ve tried to use LEFT JOIN but didnt get result like this in IMAGE.
Can someone give me a hint or write query for this?

Thank you.

Comment: No images please..post as text which we can use..also table1 seems to serve no purpose and publish what you have otherwise it just looks like you want us to do your homework for you.

Comment: Table_1 has purpose, because  there are more columns containing various information that I didn't show for simplicity, so I showed only the most important

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I did it in **microsoft sql server management studio**.
He has "query designer" and he helped me to do it right:

```
SELECT Table_1.number, Table_1.tool, SUM(Table_2.value) AS Sum
FROM Table_1
LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON Table_1.number = Table_2.number AND Table_1.tool = Table_2.tool
GROUP BY Table_1.number, Table_1.tool
```

Thank you anyway, by!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `LEFT JOIN` and `SUM` function.

```
SELECT table_1.NUMBER, table_1.TOOL, SUM(table_2.VALUE) AS SUM
FROM table_1
LEFT JOIN table_2 ON table_1.NUMBER = table_2.NUMBER AND table_1.TOOL = table_2.TOOL
GROUP BY table_1.NUMBER, table_1.TOOL;
```

This query will join the two tables based on matching `NUMBER` and `TOOL` columns, and then group the results by `NUMBER` and `TOOL`. The SUM function is used to calculate the sum of values from `VALUE` column in `table_2` for each group.

db<>fiddle [output](https://dbfiddle.uk/YMqWQde4)